# Function fread not terminating string by \0

Tags: c, fread

New to files in C, trying to read a file via fread

Here's the content of the file:

```
line1 how
```

Code used:

```
char c[6];
fread(c,1,5,f1)
```

When outputting var 'c', the contents appear with a random character at the end (eg: line1*)

Does fread not terminate the string or am I missing something?

Comment: `fread` only reads bytes into buffers. it knows nothing of what you call a string.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. The `fread` function simply reads a number of elements, it has no notion of "strings".

- You can add the NUL terminator yourself
- You can use `fgets` / `fscanf` instead

Personally I would go with `fgets`.

Comment: for those interested, an example implementation to remove newline from fgets is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input

Answer (score 4):

Sorry i'm a little late to the party.

No, fread doesn't handle this for you. It must be done manually.
Luckily its not hard.
I like to use fread()'s return to set the NUL like so:

```
char buffer[16+1]; /*leaving room for '\0' */
x = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 16, stream);
buffer[x]='\0';
```

and now you have yourself a \0 terminated string, and as a bonus, we have a nifty variable x, which actually saves us the trouble of running strlen() if we ever needed it later. neat!

Answer (score 1):

The [man page for fread](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread) says nothing about adding a terminating zero at the end of the file.

If you want to be safe, initialize all the bytes in your c array to be zero (via [bzero](http://linux.die.net/man/3/bzero) or something like that) and when you read in, you'll then have a terminating null.

I've linked the two man pages for `fread` and `bzero` and I hope that helps you out.

Comment: [`bzero()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/bzero.3.html) is deprecated (and has been removed from POSIX.1-2008) in favour of [`memset()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3p.html).